# Web service on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, wcf, .net-core, servicestack

Post the question in a different way, because the previous one was closed because it was opinion-based.
In the past I have developed several .NET applications that consumes WCF services hosted on IIS with MSSQL database.
Now the company is asking me a technology switch (for licensing reasons - current MS server is getting old and needs to be replaced) and I have do do the same but with a Linux server, so I need that the same .NET applications to connect to this server to retrieve the data in the same way that they do now with MSSQL (service reference).
So I need to rewrite the WCF service to a new technology that could be hosted in Linux. I know for sure that I have to learn a new technology to do that but I would like to be sure I choose the right one.
These are my actual skills :

- Writing C# code
- Writing VB.NET code
- SQL and MySQL
- Some Python basics

This is what I have done so far :

- Build a Linux test machine with Debian distro and installed Mono and .Net Core
- Installed MariaDb database and built table schema

Do you think that ServiceStack could be a good choice to fit my needs?
If so, what are the suggested steps to getting startet with it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you think that ServiceStack could be a good choice to fit my needs?

So [ServiceStack runs on .NET Core](https://docs.servicestack.net/netcore) and Mono but you shouldn't consider Mono for Web Apps as .NET Core is far more performant, resilient & better supported.

ServiceStack includes a code-first ORM in [OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) that you can use to quickly develop DB Apps which supports MySql/MariaDB.

ServiceStack also supports [AutoQuery](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms) where it can implement full Queryable Services for your OrmLite data models with just a [simple Typed Request DTO](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#clients-continue-to-benefit-from-a-typed-api) declaration.

And in the pre-release version (now available from [v5.8.1 on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget)) it also supports [AutoCrud](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/autocrud-preview/8298) and [AutoGen AutoCrud Services](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/autogen-autocrud-services/8528) which makes it possible to rapidly develop full CRUD APIs with declarative Request DTOs.

All these features are supported and perform even better on .NET Core thanks to its leaner & faster runtime & thanks to its cross-platform support you can take advantage of the [simpler & superior tools and Services for hosting & deployment](https://docs.servicestack.net/netcore-deploy-rsync) in the Linux ecosystem.

> If so, what are the suggested steps to getting startet with it?

I'd recommend following the [Getting Started section](https://docs.servicestack.net/create-your-first-webservice) and reading the [Background Concept docs](https://docs.servicestack.net/what-is-a-message-based-web-service) if you're new to ServiceStack to get a background understanding on its design & goals.